# How to run cron job with zend framework 2

Tags: php, cron, zend-framework2

I have application built in Zend Framework 2. I would like to set cron job for updating my products. I know scripts such as this should be run from outside of public folder, but unfortunately my script in cron needs to use framework files.
How can I do this?
The only way I figured out is to run script from outside of public folder then add some hash or password and redirect to

```
www.domain.com/cron/test
```

So I will have all framework functionality.
Will it be secure? Maybe there is a other way?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I strongly recommend to use CLI for such requirement.

1. Create a ConsoleController with an updateAction() inside the application module.
2. Add a [console route](https://zf2.readthedocs.org/en/latest/modules/zend.console.routes.html) to your application module's `module.config.php`:

   ```
   array(
       'router' => array(
           'routes' => array(
           ...
           )
       ),

   'console' => array(
       'router' => array(
           'routes' => array(
               'cronroute' => array(
                   'options' => array(
                       'route'    => 'updateproducts',
                       'defaults' => array(
                           'controller' => 'Application\Controller\Console',
                           'action' => 'update'
                       )
                   )
               )
           )
       )
   )
   );
   ```
3. Now open the terminal and

   ```
   $ cd /path/to/your/project
   $ php public/index.php updateproducts
   ```

Thats all. Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks, I'll give it a try. Just one question. Is your method safe? It won't be accessible by HTTP?

Comment: Yes it won't be accessible by HTTP. From the documentation: `"Console Routes will only be processed when the application is run inside console (terminal) window. They have no effect in web (http) request and will be ignored. It is possible to define only HTTP routes (only web application) or only Console routes (which means we want a console-only application which will refuse to run in a browser)."` Check out: http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.2/en/modules/zend.console.routes.html

Comment: Thanks, I wanted to be sure. I'll accept your answer after I check it. Probably it's going to be tomorrow. Thanks for help!

Answer (score 2):

I found the solution at collabnet (Which is now dead).

I am copying the solution here as ColabEdit sometimes removes posts:

```
<?php
/*
Cron directory setup:

Cron
    config
        module.config.php
    src
        Cron
            Controller
                IndexController.php
    autoload_classmap.php
    Module.php                

NOTES: Remember to include the Cron module in the main config file (trunk/config/application.config.php)

Once you have the route in place, write your cron and call it from your webhost cron manager.

*/

// Cron/config/module.config.php
return array(
    // Placeholder for console routes
    'controllers' => array(
        'invokables' => array(
            'Cron\Controller\IndexController' => 'Cron\Controller\IndexController'
        ),
    ),
    'console' => array(
        'router' => array(
            'routes' => array(
                //CRON RESULTS SCRAPER
                'my-first-route' => array(
                    'type'    => 'simple',       // <- simple route is created by default, we can skip that
                    'options' => array(
                    'route'    => 'hello',
                    'defaults' => array(
                        'controller' => 'Cron\Controller\IndexController',
                        'action'     => 'index'
                        )
                    )
                )

            ),
        ),
    ),


);

<?php
// Cron/src/Cron/Controller/IndexController.php
namespace Cron\Controller;

use Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractActionController;

class IndexController extends AbstractActionControlle
{
    public function indexAction()
    {
        echo "hello";
        echo "\r\n";
    }
}

From the console navigate to trunk (or public_html) (the directory before public) and run:

path/to/trunk>php public/index.php hello

hello
path/to/trunk>
```

Comment: above link is dead!