# Where do I point my Cron job path?

Tags: php, zend-framework, cron, zend-framework2

I am using Zend Framework 2 and would like to run a Cron job.  I have built a module to handle all my cron jobs.  Within my CronController I would like to run an action.

**Cron Controller**

```
   public function indexAction() 
{
     $appointmentEmail = new ReminderAppointmentEmail;                  
     $appointmentEmail->SendReminderEmail();
}
```

**Module.config**

```
'console' => array(
    'router' => array(
        'routes' => array(
            'cron' => array(
                'options' => array(
                    'route'    => 'sendTest',
                    'defaults' => array(
                        'controller' => 'Cron\Controller\Cron',
                        'action' => 'index'
                    )
                )
            )
        )
    )
)
```

Where do I point the cron job path?  Is it the controller php or the index php?  I have had trouble with both.

Below is my cron code (per other stack overflow posts)

```
usr/bin/php -q /home/**user**/public_html/public/index.php sendTest
```

Comment: It should be running based on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19768948/how-to-work-with-cron-job-in-zendframework-2?rq=1.  However it seems to be running the actual website index (based on the system gen email)

Comment: Sounds like ZF is not correctly detecting that it's a CLI request. Are you having this problem on your production server, or local machine? What is the output of `php -r "echo PHP_SAPI;"` from the same machine?

Comment: Add that line to the cron code or the zf2 action?  It is on a production server.

Comment: cgi-fcgi is the output

Comment: Okay - can you see if there's a separate PHP binary in `/usr/bin` for PHP cli? E.g. see if something like `/usr/bin/php-cli` or `/usr/bin/php5-cli` exists.

Comment: I see both these files (on a VPS).  Appreciate the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per the info in your comment, you should be able to change your cron command to:

```
/usr/bin/php-cli /home/**user**/public_html/public/index.php sendTest
```

and it should work as expected (or at least give you a better error message).