# zend framework 2.2.4 cron job returns html home page

Tags: php, zend-framework, cron

I want to execute a cron job using the sample code provided in this post: 
[How to run cron job with zend framework 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19752109/how-to-run-cron-job-with-zend-framework-2)

in my module.config.php:

```
return array(
    'console' => array(
        'router' => array(
            'routes' => array(
               'my-first-route' => array(
                    'options' => array(
                    'route'    => 'hello',
                    'defaults' => array(
                        'controller' => 'Cron\Controller\Index',
                        'action'     => 'index'
                        )
                    )
                )
            )
        )
    ),
    'controllers' => array(
        'invokables' => array(
            'Cron\Controller\Index' => 'Cron\Controller\IndexController',
        ),
    ),
);
```

in the controller:

```
namespace Cron\Controller;

use Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractActionController;

class IndexController extends AbstractActionController {

    public function indexAction() {
        echo "Cron jobs";
        echo "\r\n";
    }

}
```

in public/index.php:

```
<?php

chdir(__DIR__);
define('BASE_PATH', realpath(__DIR__));
define('PUBLIC_PATH', BASE_PATH.'/');

// Setup autoloading
require 'init_autoloader.php';

// Run the application!
Zend\Mvc\Application::init(require 'config/application.config.php')->run();
```

The commmand line I use

```
php $HOME/public_html/domain.com/public/index.php hello
```

For a reason I dont know this code returns the html version of the web application home page while the expected message is

```
Cron jobs
```

However when I create a cron.php file

```
<?php 
//cron.php
echo "Cron jobs";
```

and call in the command line it works perfect.

```
php $HOME/public_html/domain.com/public/cron.php
```

When I run `php -v` here is what I got

```
PHP 5.4.37 (cgi-fcgi) (built: Feb 13 2015 17:05:02)
Copyright (c) 1997-2014 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.4.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2014 Zend Technologies
    with the ionCube PHP Loader v4.6.1, Copyright (c) 2002-2014, by ionCube Ltd., and
    with Zend Guard Loader v3.3, Copyright (c) 1998-2013, by Zend Technologies
```

Does anyone sees something wrong?

THANK YOU IN ADVANCE.

Comment: Can you run `php -v` and add the output to your question?

Comment: Just added it to the question

Comment: Can you see if `php-cli -v` gives you anything. If yes, change your cron command to use that binary instead (so make it start `php-cli` instead of `php`). If not, you might need to hunt around to see if there's a `php-cli` executable somewhere on your server.

Comment: the php-cli command works like a charm. Can you please explain me what is the trick here? thank you

Comment: I've added an explanation as an answer. Glad you have it working.

Answer (score 1):

Servers are generally configured so that running `php` from the command line uses the CLI version of PHP, not the standard one that serves web requests. Your server is not configured this way, so your cron script was using the standard PHP binary. ZF then detects this request as a normal one, not as a console request, which is why you get the web page as a result. By calling the `php-cli` binary directly you're bypassing this problem.

Comment: Thanks for the constructive answer.