# How to schedule a cron job in ZF2?

Tags: php, cron, zend-framework2

I have setup cron job using this link: [How to run cron job with zend framework 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19752109/how-to-run-cron-job-with-zend-framework-2)

but now i don't know how to schedule this cron job to run automatically every day.
What necessary step should i take.?
Can anybody help in this. 
Thank in advance.

Comment: Did you check the zend framework documentation? Also it might depend on the system it runs on(as this usually "owns" cron)

Comment: yes, but i couldn't find the solution to schedule  a cron job in Zend framework 2.

Comment: Could you already take a look at e.g. [How to run cron job with zend framework 2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19752109/how-to-run-cron-job-with-zend-framework-2)? Skimming through this seems to offer something ... also to get you going in your case.

Comment: see the issue is, i don't have idea how to run cron automatically by scheduling it. i can manually run cron by command line using command, "index.php run cron", but how can i run same thing by scheduling it.

Comment: Ah, usually this is edited on linux via `crontab -e` for the user that calls it. `man 5 crontab` should help with the format (where to put the hour, day, minute and which "patterns" for repeated executions are allowed. Usually this would boil down to say `28 */2 * * *       /some/command` (to run /some/command every second hour 28 minutes after "full" hour) but if this command you mention drives it's own cron, then I imagine, this just needs to be put in some "autostart" after boot like place depending on your operating system.