# How to optimize cron to send bulk mails to large people?

Tags: php, cron, zend-framework2, ubuntu-14.04, mailgun

I have a marketplace where there are many sellers and each seller have multiple items to sell.I generate invoice of each item when it was sold and send it to the buyer. Now I want that at the end of each day my application make zip of all the invoices for each seller and send the zip in  email with some other details like what are the items which were sold ? It should send email to the sellers. Basically it involves 3 process:

- Get all seller from db
- Loop over seller and then search for invoices which were generated on that day
- Make zip of all the invoices
- Email the zip with some other details.
- End loop

Now I want to optimize this process. I am thinking to run a cron which will run at a particular time and do these things. As it is a synchronous process so most probably it will break during execution. How can I make it asynchronous ? I am using Zf2 and ubuntu cron.

Comment: do not use zf2 module for this, use direct php script that does this task

Comment: @raj why direct php script? don't you think it will also break during execution for large number of sellers.

Comment: do you mean break in the sense, consume more cpu time so load the server and prevent normal function, how much invoice do you expect per day? and what will be the average size of zipped invoice?, if you are talking about script timeout you can call set_time_limit(0); on the first line of the script, I had created this type of script for background service without any issues

Comment: Check also [this answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19752378/1697459)

Comment: @wilt I know about console routes but here I am asking about optimisation, how can I make it async ?

Comment: @raj My avg zipped size will be 1mb and it might be possible that some seller don't have any zip and I just need to send them simple email. What I am thinking of using some queue. If you have any script which uses some queue then please share it with me.

Comment: when you send an email there is a way to send it async